# Moving an ImageView on a circular path with certain radius

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I've been reading all posts related to animations but am unable to find a way to achieve what I am asked.

I've been asked to move an Image on a circular path with a certain radius, like here
http://www.4shared.com/photo/RtYILTLO/circularpath.html

I got the basics of animation but that's about it. Any type of tutorial or hint would be warmly welcome.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

I was browsing in search of an example which would animate an view around a certain path and found out this 
http://code.google.com/p/android-path-animation/

this code moves a button around a complex curvey path, I tried making a circle with it but in vain, would anyone help me modify this code a bit so the button moves around in circular path?

Thanks

Comment: Ah finally i did a bit of researched and found solution to my own problem. Instead of using animation to revolve an object/view around in circular path, I just stored the (x, y) cords on circle's parameter  in and array and used handler to change view's params every sec resulting in the view revolving around in circular path smoothly.

Comment: did you do all of this in the onDraw method of the view?

Comment: no just in onCreate(). I'll post some code if you dont get it.

Comment: i have the canvas, i mean the surface view and a thread that moves 6 balls. The problem is i also have another animation goin on simultaneously, but the surfaceviews thread seems to take up all the priviledge and the other animation is slowed down. why so ?

Comment: i need a lil help. i am not able to move the balls as expected :(. i managed to do so but i have another animation going on too with this one, so it blocks the main thread somehow.

Comment: can you help with a sample code? I am stuck in such kinda problem.

Answer (score 1):

at first please update [this link](http://www.4shared.com/photo/RtYILTLO/circularpath.html) it doesn't work!

to make circle animation path for after lolliPop, use this code as google [suggested](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#UsePath) :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  Path path = new Path();
  path.arcTo(0f, 0f, 1000f, 1000f, 0f, 359f, true); //with first four parameters you determine four edge of a rectangle by pixel , and fifth parameter is the path'es start point from circle 360 degree and sixth parameter is end point of path in that circle
  ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path); //at first parameter (view) put the target view
  animator.setDuration(2000);
  animator.start();
}
```